# Piezo to detect low frequency, low strain

Tags: piezo

I have been trying to detect a very low frequency, very low strain signal with different types of piezos (hobby type, hobby type enclosed in plastic casing, shielded contact mic type, and flexible piezo film type). The signal is generated from a small stream of water passing through a pipe 2" in diameter.

If I put these sensors on the pipe, and measure the AC signal directly with my oscilloscope, I cannot detect a signal. Although I have not been able to do a frequency analysis of the water pipe, I would guess that the water passing through the pipe at the frequency I'm trying to detect to be <10Hz. Additionally, the water passing through the pipe would create what I'd call "very low strain."

If I turn the water up to a "high" amount, the signal is easily detectable -- the frequency of the water is what I'd estimate 100 - 200 Hz and there is more strain on the pipe.

I have also created voltage amplifier to see if I can amplify this (undetectable) low strain signal I mentioned at the top of this post. The amp seems to only amplify noise or interference.

In short, I think that the piezos I have cannot detect a low strain <5Hz signal.

Can anyone recommend a way to detect <5Hz low strain signal? It appears ultrasonic sensors could be a solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you use a strain gauge?  (Having said that, I'm not sure that I fully understand your setup.  Some description of what you are ultimately trying to achieve with these measurement might help.)

Comment: Ultrasound and 5Hz are not going together. Also piezo is high frequency transducer (from few kHz to Mhz).

Comment: Low frequencies + Piezo strain gauge = charge amplifier. A 'normal' op-amp configuration will discharge the Piezo device very quickly.

Comment: Are you actually detecting strain, that is the change of distance between two points on the pipe? Or are you detecting acceleration, that is the rate at which the speed of part of the pipe surface is moving is changing? The first is readable all the way down to DC, but needs two points of attachment. The second has a frequency slope in its sensitivity, so no response at DC, response rising with increasing frequency, and needs only one point of attachment. You can use a 'strain gauge' in either configuration.

Comment: @NickAlexeev a strain gauge is a good idea. For now I have not been able to use one. Perhaps for the next version I will try this. Is there a strain gauge you'd recommend for detecting the strain that running water creates passing through a pipe? I was just checking out some links on Mouser for things like this: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Intersil/ISLEM-BDGSTKEV1Z/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvFkM%2fHBrKaDd40Pk5jpOwh

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes, I understand that 5Hz is a couple orders of magnitude from the ultrasonic. Basically I have been exploring the advantages of using piezo technology to detect strain and ultrasonic sensors that could detect differences in water pressure (which would indicate water flow). Using piezos seems to be more cost effective right now (inexpensive piezos can detect when "a lot" of water is running through the pipe); however, I think ultrasonic pressure sensors would be the best way to detect small fluid flows within the pipe (as is done in most commercial flowmeters).

Comment: @Chu Thanks for the call to the charge amplifier. I am currently using a high impedance FET op amp (LMC660C) in a voltage amplifier setup. I will post the schematic soon.

Answer (score 2):

To detect low frequencies with a piezo requires an extremely high impedance amplifier, for example if the element is 10nF you'd need something of the order of 3-10M ohms.

Try a low bias current CMOS op-amp with (say) 4.7M load resistor (parallel to the piezo).  Choose one with bias current << 1nA ( easy- there are parts with << 1pA).

Your circuit may not be good enough for practical use if the resistance gets much higher than a few M - condensation from the cold water, for example would have to be avoided even at the suggested resistance level.

Comment: I wonder if a TIA opamp configuration would be best?  (Physically the piezo is a current source with big shunt capacitance.)  One could even put a cap in the feedback path and integrate the current.

Answer (score 1):

For wide frequency response of a piezo consider a [Charge Amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_amplifier) instead of a voltage amplifier. The lower cutoff frequency is give by the relationship of the resistor and capacitor in the feedback loop. The opamp needs to be a high impedance JFET or CMOS type.

To test your input stage, I recommend putting the piezo element onto a speaker element and drive it at <10 Hz to verify the frequency reponse.